# http caching, using must-revalidate

Tags: http, caching

What is the correct way to use "must-revalidate" along with max-age?

what happens in these to cases:

case 1:
if I set high max-age (say 24 hours) with "must-revalidate"
will the browser check for etag changes before 24 hours have elapsed?

case 2:
if I set max-age as zero with must-revalidate
I understand the browser will always send a request, but will it download if there are no eTag changes? or always download irrespective of changes.

just to clarify, I know what happens where there is no "must-revalidate" specified. My question in both cases is about what is different when using "must-revalidate"

Just to add a background to what I am trying to achieve. I have some js files which are loaded dynamically in a webpage. When the contents are changed, I want the files to be refreshed and not served from the cache. Else if there are no changes I always need the file to be loaded from the cache.